# ¿ Como hacer referencia en package.json a otro modulo de mi proyecto?

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs, api

Hola mi aplicación creada con node.js tengo varios modulos: la base de datos, la Api, servicio del cliente, etc...
Bien, en alguno he de hacer referencia de otro en el archivo package.json pero no se si lo estoy haciendo bien, pues al empezar a enlazarlos, no termina de funcionar.
Tengo todos los módulos dentro del mismo directorio, cada uno en su directorio. 
El archivo package.json a veces me marca el error :  ***no está instalado este módulo***, error porque si está en `node_modules`.
¿ Estoy llamando bien al módulo en el archivo package.json ?
`"michaelgram-client": "file:../michaelgram-client"`,
Gracias, muestro parte de package.json

> EDITO: Para añadir código que me sugirieron.

```js
"license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.239.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "concurrently": "^3.5.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "empty-element": "^1.0.0",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "file-extension": "^4.0.2",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "intl-messageformat": "^2.2.0",
    "intl-relativeformat": "^2.1.0",
    "materialize-css": "^0.100.2",
    "michaelgram-client": "file:../michaelgram-client",
    "multer": "^1.3.0",
    "multer-s3": "^2.7.0",
    "node-pre-gyp": "^0.9.1",
    "page": "^1.8.6",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-facebook": "^2.1.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "pug": "^2.0.3",
    "readable-stream": "^2.3.6",
    "superagent": "^3.8.3",
    "title": "^3.2.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^2.0.0",
    "yo-yo": "^1.4.1"
  },
```

> ESTE ES EL MODULO QUE TRAIGO HASTA EL MODULO QUE ME DA LOS PROBLEMAS

```js
//PACKAGE.JSON DEL MODULO QUE TRAIGO

{
  "name": "michaelgram-client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Michaelgram API Client",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "standard",
    "test": "npm run lint && ava"
  },
  "standard": {
    "parser": "babel-eslint"
  },
  "author": "Miguel Espeso ",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "ava": "^0.25.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.3",
    "nock": "^9.2.6",
    "standard": "^11.0.1",
    "uuid-base62": "^0.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bluebird": "^3.5.1",
    "request": "^2.34.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Podrías mostrar el package.json de tu otro módulo?

Comment: En ese package.json tienes como `main: "index.js"`. Es así? Tú archivo de entrada es `index.js`?

Comment: Pues ese creo que es el error, esto estaría bien `file:../michaelgram-client`. Cambiando `"main": "index.js"` por `"main": "server.js"(o path/donde/tengas/server.js)`resuelve el problema?

Comment: Probare, pero si me dices que `file:../michaelgram-client` le llamo bien al modulo, perfecto, mi duda era esa, pues hay veces que marca como error el editor, como que no le tengo instalado. Gracias. Si quieres puedes poner como respuesta y la aceptare.

Comment: Puedes comprobar que está bien de la siguiente manera: 1.borra esa entrada en las dependencias. 2. `npm install ../michaelgram-client --save` ;P

Comment: Perfecto, borre, instale y se volvio a instalar. Me da vulnerabilidades pero se instalo tal y como estaba :LAS VULNERABILIDADES: + michaelgram-client@1.0.0
updated 1 package in 22.803s
[!] 21 vulnerabilities found [13310 packages audited]
    Severity: 5 Low | 14 Moderate | 2 High
    Run `npm audit` for more detail

Comment: Eso son vulnerabilidades de paquetes de terceros que usas. La últimas versiones de npm te dan esa información al instalar paquetes.

Comment: Si quieres añadir respuesta...puedes hacerlo, pues funcionó todo lo que dijiste. Poniendo la forma en la que se verifica el módulo, quitar de package.json e instalando desde npm, creo que podría ayudar a otros. MUchas gracias, voy a borrar algún comentario que llenamos esto mucho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplificando la estructura del proyecto.

**Estructura del proyecto**

```
~root
  - moduloA
     - index.js
     - ...
  - moduloB
    -index.js
    - ...
```

Supongamos que estoy realizando el módulo `moduloA` cuyo archivo de entrada (`main`) es `index.js`.
En ese package.json debe haber:

```
{
 ...
 "main": "index.js",
 ...
}
```

Ahora estamos trabajando en otro módulo `moduloB`.

Si queremos instalar el módulo local `moduloA` teniendo en cuenta la estructura del proyecto, haríamos:

```
npm install ../moduloA --save
```

En cualquier parte de móduloB podrás cargar tu módulo:

```
import ... from 'moduloA' (o require('moduloA'))
```